# Calling a function in another thread C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, directshow, rfid

I don't know how to put this but I'll try my best.

I have a Windows form application which uses a webcam to take a photo of a user which works fine, I'm using the directshownet library found here http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/ and have used the DxSnap sample to take the photo.

The next part of the application uses an RFID tag reader that once a tag is scanned, it calls the take photo method. And this is where the problem is coming in, because the RFID listen method is run in a separate thread to the GUI thread, because it is an infinite while loop.

The class that is used to take the picture takes an instance of a picturebox control as a parameter for it's constructor, which is created in the main thread, and i think this is where the problem is.

Each part of the application works fine separately but when i try to call the method to take the photo from the listener thread all hell breaks loose and the app crashes.

Does anybody know how I could call a method of the object that is initialized in the main thread (that takes the photo) from the listener thread?

I've tried delegate and invoke, but can't figure it out as i don't want to manipulate the control directly, but rather let the object do it in the main thread.

Here's some code:

```
    private Capture cam;
    private int portIndex = -1;
    private ArrayList AlreadyOpenPortList = new ArrayList();
    private byte readerAddr = 0;
    private Thread listenThread;
    IntPtr m_ip = IntPtr.Zero;

    public podiumForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // scanner and camera startup
        startCam();
        openComs();
        openRF();
        startListening();
    }


 private void startListening()
    {
        listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Listen));
        listenThread.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method of retrieving code tag details from reader
    /// </summary>
    private void Listen()        
    {
        int fCmdRet = 0x30;
        byte state = 1;
        byte AFI = 00;
        byte[] DSFIDAndUID = new byte[9];
        byte cardNumber = 0;
        string strDSFIDAndUID = "";
        byte outputSet;

        if (!GetCurrentUsePort())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Open ComPort, Please");
            return;
        }


        while (true)
        {
            fCmdRet = StaticClassReaderA.Inventory(ref readerAddr, ref state, ref AFI, DSFIDAndUID, ref cardNumber, portIndex);
            if (fCmdRet == 0)
            {
                outputSet = 0;
                fCmdRet = StaticClassReaderA.SetGeneralOutput(ref readerAddr, ref outputSet, portIndex);
                strDSFIDAndUID = ByteArrayToHexString(DSFIDAndUID).Replace(" ", "");
                outputSet = 3;
                fCmdRet = StaticClassReaderA.SetGeneralOutput(ref readerAddr, ref outputSet, portIndex);
                SavePic(strDSFIDAndUID.Substring(2, 16));
                //MessageBox.Show(strDSFIDAndUID.Substring(2, 16));

                //ShutDown();
            }
        }
    }

private void SavePic(string text)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        // Release any previous buffer
        if (m_ip != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(m_ip);
            m_ip = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        // here's where it crashes
        // capture image
        m_ip = cam.Click();
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(cam.Width, cam.Height, cam.Stride, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, m_ip);
        cam.Dispose();

        // If the image is upsidedown
        b.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
        pbPic.Image = b;

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        MessageBox.Show("Here " + text);
    }


private void startCam()
    {
        const int VIDEODEVICE = 0; // zero based index of video capture device to use
        const int VIDEOWIDTH = 640; // Depends on video device caps
        const int VIDEOHEIGHT = 480; // Depends on video device caps
        const int VIDEOBITSPERPIXEL = 24; // BitsPerPixel values determined by device

        cam = new Capture(VIDEODEVICE, VIDEOWIDTH, VIDEOHEIGHT, VIDEOBITSPERPIXEL, pbPic);
    }


// method in capture class
 public IntPtr Click()
    {
        int hr;

        // get ready to wait for new image
        m_PictureReady.Reset();
        m_ipBuffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Math.Abs(m_stride) * m_videoHeight);

        try
        {
            m_WantOne = true;

            // If we are using a still pin, ask for a picture
            if (m_VidControl != null)
            {
                // CRASHES HERE with : System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
                // Tell the camera to send an image
                hr = m_VidControl.SetMode(m_pinStill, VideoControlFlags.Trigger);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }

            // Start waiting
            if (!m_PictureReady.WaitOne(9000, false))
            {
                throw new Exception("Timeout waiting to get picture");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(m_ipBuffer);
            m_ipBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            throw;
        }

        // Got one
        return m_ipBuffer;
    }
```

Comment: The answer is Control.Invoke, show us what didn't work there.

Comment: then narrow it down and show us relevant parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) class; it allows you to dispatch work back on the main (UI) thread in a manner that is agnostic of how that mechanism actually works (and therefore works with WinForms and WPF). Therefore you don't need to have a reference to a Control to call Invoke on.

It is what [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) uses behind the scenes (you may also be able to use `BackgroundWorker`, depending on what you're trying to do, which is slightly easier to work with).

Comment: So instead of using a custom thread rather use a backgroundworker?

Comment: Yes, and then you could use its `ProgressChanged` event and `ReportProgress` method to marshal a method call back to the UI thread. This uses `SynchronizationContext` under the covers to marshall the call.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Image image = (Image)pictureBox.Invoke ((Func<Image>) delegate { return pictureBox.Image; });
```